# Closing a browser tab that has been opened by a desktop application

Tags: javascript, java, browser

In order to use reddit oauth, I need to open a browser window

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+url);
```

Which let's the user press "Allow" and then it redirect to

```
http://localhost:8000/auth
```

Which is a simple http web server in java.

**Is there any way to close that tab remotely or from the javascript?** I don't want to be left with a blank page every time a user logs in.

I would use a WebView to do the oauth process but then  you need to enter the user/pass every time even if the user is already logged in on his browser.

Comment: Doesn't [exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) return a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) that you can [destroy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy())

Comment: I tried that earlier and it doesn't do anything. I can't even find the process it returns using it's handle from the tasklist so I assume it gets closed on it's own and it's not the same process as the browser tab.

Comment: Oh yea, you are using `rundll32` which will spawn a subprocess so you won't have a handle reference. I think the only way then would be to execute the actual browser, e.g. `iexplore.exe` since its included in all Windows up to 10 so far. To try to find the default browser you would have to use some registry api to find the key that holds the default application path